# Orthonormality of Wannier functions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, tight-binding

In "Modern Condensed Matter Physics" by Girvin and Yang, a question invites the reader to prove the orthonormality of the Wannier functions. My proof will be complete if
$$
\langle n',0\vert n,\ell'\rangle
=\delta_{nn'}\langle 0\vert\ell'\rangle
$$
holds, where $n$, $n'$ label band indices, and $\ell$ refers to the unit cell in a Bravais crystal. How can I show this is true? Any hints will be appreciated.

The book mentions that different orbitals centered on one and the same atom are orthogonal; *i.e*.
$$
\langle n\ell \vert n'\ell'\rangle =\delta_{nn'}
\quad\mbox{if}~\ell=\ell'
$$
but says nothing about the case $\ell\ne\ell'$.